# Why return a func in Golang

Tags: go

I was looking into golang contexts recently, and found that the `WithCancel()` is implemented in an interesting way.

```
func WithCancel(parent Context) (ctx Context, cancel CancelFunc) {
    if parent == nil {
        panic("cannot create context from nil parent")
    }
    c := newCancelCtx(parent)
    propagateCancel(parent, &c)
    return &c, func() { c.cancel(true, Canceled) }
}
```

`WithCancel()` returns a ctx, and also a func to cancel the very same context. Why is this done rather than introducing the `.Cancel()` as a func of the type itself, like

```
func (c *cancelCtx) Cancel() {
  c.cancel(true, Canceled)
}
```

I understand using a func return type allows you to run a different func depending on runtime conditions, but there's no dynamic here - it's always the same func. Is this just because for the functional paradigm?

Reference: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/master:src/context/context.go;l=232-239?q=context&ss=go%2Fgo

Comment: No need to introduce new data types when functional programming works perfectly well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all contexts are cancel-able. You could argue that for those that aren't, the `Cancel()` method could be a no-op.

But then you would always have to call `Cancel()` whenever you work with `context.Context` because you don't (can't) know whether it truly needs cancelling. This would be unnecessary in a lot of cases, would make code slower (cancel functions are usually called deferred) and would bloat the code.

Also, the power of cancelling a context is for its creator only. The creator may choose to share this responsibility by passing / sharing the cancel function, but if doesn't, sharing the context alone does not allow (*should not* allow) cancelling it. If `Cancel()` would be part of `context.Context`, this restriction could not be enforced. For details, see [Cancel context from child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66679577/cancel-context-from-child/66679667#66679667).

Interfaces–especially those widely used–should be small and a minimum, not containing all, rarely useful things.